# Php&Laravel passing encrypted object via url

Tags: php, laravel

I am building simple reservation system.
In car listing page, i will send all data to next page with url encryption method. 
I have `$o` object which contains, car details. 
I cannot pass this object with `base64_decode()` function because it needs string parameter.

So, how can i pass this object to next page with encryption?

Thanks

Comment: What about `json_encode`? Or `serialize`? You can design your own lightweight serializer/deserializer, after all.

Comment: Could you not create a nullable table and update the row as you go along the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I think I would do foreach and **base64_ecode()** each row...